# How to create a trigger for multiple schemas?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, trigger

One of my PostgreSQL databases contains different schemas which share the same structure.

```
-- schema region_a
CREATE TABLE region_a.point (
gid serial NOT NULL,
geom geometry(point, SRID),
attribute_sample varchar(255),
CONSTRAINT point_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
);

CREATE TABLE region_a.polygon (
gid serial NOT NULL,
geom geometry(polygon, SRID),
attribute varchar(255),
CONSTRAINT polygon_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
);

-- schema region_b
CREATE TABLE region_b.point (
gid serial NOT NULL,
geom geometry(point, SRID),
attribute_sample varchar(255),
CONSTRAINT point_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
);

CREATE TABLE region_b.polygon (
gid serial NOT NULL,
geom geometry(polygon, SRID),
attribute varchar(255),
CONSTRAINT polygon_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
);

-- schema region_c
-- ...
```

Now I wonder how to create a trigger to add sample points on the polygon features within a schema.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample_attribute_from_polygon()
RETURNS trigger AS $body$
    BEGIN
        NEW.attribute_sample = (SELECT attribute FROM polygon
        WHERE ST_Within(NEW.geom, polygon.geom));
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; 

CREATE TRIGGER sample_attribute_from_polygon_tg BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON point FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sample_attribute_from_polygon();
```

Is there any way to use the same trigger for all schemas? I'm looking for a solution that's also working when renaming a schema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind a trigger function to as many tables as you want; just execute a `CREATE TRIGGER` statement for each binding.  Make sure to schema-qualify the table name in your statement (`BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON a.point` etc.)  If you have a large number of schemas, you could generate the SQL dynamically by iterating over the rows in `information_schema.schemata`.

If the trigger function needs to do something different depending on which table it's running on, you can access the table schema and name through `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA` and `TG_TABLE_NAME`.  (See [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) for all available variables).

In your case, a dynamic trigger function might be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample_attribute_from_polygon()
RETURNS trigger AS $body$
    BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT attribute FROM ' || TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '.polygon WHERE ST_Within($1, polygon.geom) LIMIT 1' 
      USING NEW.geom 
      INTO NEW.attribute_sample;
    RETURN NEW;
    END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Great, the trigger function works fine after duplicating or renaming a schema!

Comment: I also have to update all point geometries within a polygon geometry when editing the polygon geometry. Do I need a second trigger function to do this?

Comment: Yes, I'd think so.

Comment: I've tried `EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '.point SET attribute_sample = new.attribute WHERE st_within(point.geom, $1)'
USING NEW.geom;
RETURN NEW;` but QGIS says `missing FROM-clause entry for table "new"`. I suppose there is something wrong with my syntax.

Comment: You could set up a trigger on your polygons table, running `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` that sets the `attribute_sample` in the relevant records of the points table to `NULL`.  It doesn't actually matter what you set the value to, because this update is itself going to trigger a refresh against the just--updated polygon table.  Multiple interacting triggers can get confusing very quickly.

Comment: @ dbaston Thanks a lot, `EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '.point SET attribute_sample = NULL WHERE st_within(point.geom, $1)'
USING NEW.geom;
RETURN NEW;` is working. But when deleting a polygon the `attribute_sample` values of the points within are not set to NULL.

Comment: It sounds like you also need a trigger to fire `AFTER DELETE` on the polygons table.